# Problems getting page URL after the runtime changes on Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

It seems that after the change to the new Apps Script runtime powered by Chrome V8, the ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() function does not seem to be getting the correct App URL. When I try to move to other pages on my apps I get an error page saying "Sorry, unable to open the file at present.". The same apps were working fine before the change. Any suggestions?

Comment: Search the Issue Tracker for any current issues.  [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues)  If you find the same issue, then click the star.  You can revert back to `runtimeVersion: DEPRECATED_ES5` in the appsscript.json manifest file.  From the code editor, click "View" and "Show manifest file."

Comment: I just tested and it works for me. Your script/project is deployed, right? Mind sharing some code or at least a minimum working example that fails for you?

Comment: Could you share your code so it can be reproduced, please?